# Swift delegate doesn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm using [PanelKit](https://github.com/louisdh/panelkit) for an iOS app that I'm developing right now.

I have set up a panel, which is a ViewController, and have set up a button in that ViewController. When pressed, I want a picture to be displayed in another ViewController (the main VC that's instantiated when the app is launched). I'm using a delegate for this. However, my delegate function never gets executed. Here's my code:

Delegate:

```
protocol IMGPickerDelegate: class {
    func didFinishPicking(_ imageData: UIImage)
}
```

Panel ViewController:

```
class IMGLibraryViewController: UIViewController, PanelContentDelegate {
    weak var delegate: IMGPickerDelegate?

    @IBAction func fireButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let imageSample = UIImage(named: "sample")!
        didPickImage(imageDData: imageSample)
    }

    func didPickImage(imageDData: UIImage) {
        delegate?.didFinishPicking(imageDData)
    }
```

Main ViewController:

```
class ImageDisplayViewController: UIViewController, IMGPickerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageDisplayViewOutlet: UIImageView!

    var imgLibrary = IMGLibraryViewController()

    func didFinishPicking(_ imageData: UIImage) {
        imageDisplayViewOutlet.image = imageData
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imgLibrary.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: Show how you display the `IMGLibraryViewController` from `ImageDisplayViewController`.

Comment: By calling PanelKit's `showPopover()`. It isn't displayed from `ImageDisplayViewController`, but rather from `ViewController`. `ViewController` contains a Container View, and that's `ImageDisplayViewController`. It's linked through the Storyboard using an embed segue. Basically exactly like PanelKit's example project which you can find in the GitHub repo that I've linked above.

Comment: It is almost certain that the instance of `IMGLibraryViewController` in `imgLibrary` is not the instance that is being shown.  You need to set the delegate on the appropriate instance (You can get it from `prepareForSegue` for the embed segue)

Comment: Thanks, that's most definitely it! Unfortunately, I can't figure out where to use `prepareForSegue` and hence, where to set the delegate on the appropriate instance. I've uploaded the project to GitHub. Would you mind pointing me to the right line in my project? I think I'm lacking a single line of code here. Here's the project: https://github.com/horrion/DelegateProblem

Edit: If you can provide that line of code and where it should be located as an answer (not a comment), I'll mark it as the accepted answer.